# Are workarounds considered relevant answers?

Tags: discussion, answers

Sometimes an answer can solve the OP's *practical problem* although it does not address the OP's exact *question*. Should I post answers like that?

For example consider [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39879196/2069380) answer which received 3 downvotes and makes me wonder.

Comment: In principle there is nothing wrong with that. I believe the simplest explanation of this scenario is that the downvoters disapprove your specific workaround, rather than workarounds in general.

Comment: In general, I think it's better to solve the OP's problem than answer their question; this often requires a lot more information than they initially present (which they're often surprisingly unwilling to part with) but is ultimately more satisfying (for me, anyway).

Comment: There's nothing wrong with workarounds. For your specific example, it was a _bad_ workaround.

Comment: *better to solve the OP's problem than answer their question; .. but is ultimately more satisfying*  .. it also tends to lead to more thorough answers, which are more beneficial for the community as well, IMO.

Comment: If there is an actual solution to the problem answer with the solution. Keep workarounds for situations where what the OP wants cannot be done in a proper way.

Comment: For what it's worth, I have often been disappointed when I find a thread that is _exactly_ what I want based on the title only to find that the "answer" is a workaround that doesn't solve the title and stated problem.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

From the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) (emphasis mine):

> What, specifically, is the question asking for? Make sure your answer provides that – **or a viable alternative**.

So, yes, workarounds *can* make good answers. If this is also true for a *specific* answer, that's for the community to decide.

Comment: Well, my question can rephrased as "Are workarounds considered *viable* alternative?" but I got your point. +1

Comment: @OhadEytan a workaround is an alternative by definition. *Viable* depends on two things: does the workaround actually work, and does it do what the questioner requires.

Comment: I agree with this answer. Workarounds can be invaluable. Sometimes they are the only solution and sometimes understanding how to work around a problem is more valuable than a direct solution due to its reuse value in similar but different future problems. Not to mention the "time value" concept. I'd rather have a workaround today than a direct solution tomorrow (!).

Answer (score 16):

That looks like a horrendously hacky work around for OP's problem.  But there's a worse problem for it on SO: it is completely localized for OP's problem.  The next person who comes along wondering how to deal with multi-line expressions in Python AST is going to find that answer completely useless.  I would have down voted that answer if I'd seen it (but haven't because I don't think it deserves Meta-effect!).

Comment: As much as I know the main purpose of an answer should be the OP itself, the "next person" benefits are a good *side effect* rather than a demand.

Comment: @OhadEytan eh no, quite the other way around. The fact that the person asking the question is helped is a good side effect, but SO tailors to the masses and not the individual.

Comment: @Gimby can you give some reference for that? Maybe it worth another meta-question

Comment: I am  concerned more about the wider audience than the localized op question. Because we are trying to pull them toward best practices. And more eyes will follow than the op eyes.

Comment: @OhadEytan No specific reference, but it's implicit in the question close-vote reasons. This is the very reason that questions which are too broad or too specific are closed: they're unlikely to invite answers which help more people than the OP.

Comment: @Gimby it's a more complicated relationship than that. I always write my answers with posterity in mind, but my *motivation* is usually to help a single person in the moment.